# Extracting HTML code from websites by looping through list of URLs

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping, automation

I'm using Excel VBA to launch an IE browser tab based on the URL in each of the rows in column D. Then the relevant HTML code is extracted based on pre-defined classes and populated in columns A - C.

Pretty sure I missed a step. The process stops at D2 and does not proceed to extract HTML from the next URLs (in cells D3, D4, etc).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
Sub useClassnames()
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim shellWins As New ShellWindows
Dim IE_TabURL As String
Dim intRowPosition As Integer

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False

intRowPosition = 2

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate Sheet1.Range("D" & intRowPosition)

While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1

While Sheet1.Range("D" & intRowPosition) <> vbNullString
    IE.navigate Sheet1.Range("D" & intRowPosition), CLng(2048)

    While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

    intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1

Wend

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page…"
DoEvents
Loop

Set html = IE.document
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("container-bs")

Dim count As Long
Dim erow As Long
count = 0
For Each element In elements
If element.className = "container-bs" Then
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByClassName("pull-left")(count + 1).innerHTML
Cells(erow, 2) = html.getElementsByClassName("description")(count).innerHTML
Cells(erow, 3) = html.getElementsByClassName("related-articles")(count).innerHTML
count = count + 1
End If
Next element

Range("A2:C2000").Select
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 36
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lines

```
Set html = IE.document
Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("container-bs")
```

etc happen after the `While` loop. It needs to be inside.

---

Your `If` statement:

```
If element.className = "container-bs"
```

should be redundant as you are already looping over a collection of that classname; so I have removed this.

---

You are not working off `element` in the loop, so essentially you are using it to control your incremented counter variable. This suggests you can use a better coding strategy for retrieving the items of interest.

---

Always state the parent worksheet and don't rely on implicit Activesheet references - that is bug prone.

---

I would expect a structure more like as follows (I cannot account for refactoring to remove `element`)

---

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub UseClassnames()
    Dim element As IHTMLElement, elements As IHTMLElementCollection, ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, intRowPosition As Long

    intRowPosition = 2
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = True

    While Sheet1.Range("D" & intRowPosition) <> vbNullString

        If intRowPosition = 2 Then
            ie.navigate Sheet1.Range("D" & intRowPosition)
        Else
            ie.navigate Sheet1.Range("D" & intRowPosition), CLng(2048)
        End If

        While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = ie.document
        Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("container-bs")

        Dim count As Long, erow As Long

        count = 0

        For Each element In elements
            erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            With Sheet1
                .Cells(erow, 1) = html.getElementsByClassName("pull-left")(count + 1).innerHTML
                .Cells(erow, 2) = html.getElementsByClassName("description")(count).innerHTML
                .Cells(erow, 3) = html.getElementsByClassName("related-articles")(count).innerHTML
            End With
            count = count + 1
        Next element

        intRowPosition = intRowPosition + 1
    Wend
    With Sheet1
        .Range("A2:C2000").Select
        .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 36
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explanation, very helpful indeed. Something seems to have gone wrong with the website I'm scraping from, I will re-test this.

Comment: Is this still presenting problems?

Comment: I just got a chance to try this out and refactored to remove `element`. Worked like a charm, can't thank you enough!

Comment: Glad it got there.